# Doesn't show <tbody> in html

Tags: java, html, angularjs

I would like to design table with angularjs on index.html.
Then showing index.html and  is okay, but `<tbody ng-init="getAll()"` - not show...

I put index.html:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tbody ng-init="getAll()">
                <tr ng-repeat="d in employees">
                <td>{{d.id}}</td>
                <td>{{d.name}}</td>
                <td>{{d.designation}}</td>
                <td>{{d.expertise}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="editInfo(d.id)" title="Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteInfo(d.id)" title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
            </table>
```

app.js:

```
$scope.getAll = function() {

    $http.get('employees').then(function(response, status, header, config){
        $scope.employees = response.data;
    });
}
```

my web app:
[image]

**How can I resolve this?**

Comment: Have you debugged this code? Does the server correctly return you the data?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing on project by springboot and Mysql server.
I have tried to put $get http://localhost:8081/autoeshop/employees and json showed a list of employee

Comment: This is working to connect between application and server except desiging html

Comment: Try logging `console.log(response.data);` to see what are you getting from the server.

Comment: How does this relate to Java?

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure You are getting data from `$http` call. your angular code is correct and working fine for me.

Also you can add some text when no data in `$scope.employees`

try this:

```js
angular.module("myapp", [])
  .controller("mycontroller", function($scope, $timeout, $http) {
    $scope.employees = [];

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.employees = [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Aagam',
          designation: 'Developer',
          expertise: 'Java Script'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Akshay',
          designation: 'Developer',
          expertise: 'python'
        }
      ];
    }, 3000);

    /*$http.get('employees').then(function(response, status, header, config) {
      $scope.employees = response.data;
    });*/
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
  <div ng-hide="employees && employees.length">
    No-Data Available
  </div>
  <table class="table table-hover" ng-show="employees && employees.length">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-init="getAll()">
      <tr ng-repeat="d in employees">
        <td>{{d.id}}</td>
        <td>{{d.name}}</td>
        <td>{{d.designation}}</td>
        <td>{{d.expertise}}</td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="editInfo(d.id)" title="Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteInfo(d.id)" title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
```

Comment: Console hasn't error message any.
You are good to offer some code. But I'm requiring used database by mysql

Comment: sorry I did't get you. Plz explain what you exactly want.